# Programmatic interface to Rhino compiler?

Tags: javascript, jvm, bytecode, rhino

I've found [Rhino JS Compiler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_JavaScript_Compiler) documentation, which says how to compile JS -> JVM, but the only documented interface I've found is for the command-line tool.  Also, it seems to be built for the "script (list of commands)" -> "runnable Main() method" use case, and not (for example) subclassing a specific Java class.

Is there an easy way to use the Rhino code generator to generate a .class file for a class I define?  Specifically, I'm trying to implement an interface for use with a Java library that will turn around and use inspection on it, so the normal interpreter mechanism of implementing an interface in Rhino won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with these specifics of Rhino, but the Java documentation on javax.script has a very straightforward section titled [Implementing Java Interfaces](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jsimplement). Perhaps this will be helpful.

Comment: As I said above, the normal interpreter mechanism is of no use here.  (Doubly so for the Oracle/Sun Java Rhino because, as mentioned on the page you linked, it doesn't support JavaScript-to-bytecode compilation at all.)